# background image opacity at the center of div without using two divs

Tags: css, opacity

I want to have a background image at the center of a div (the width is fixed, but the height is content dependent, so I wouldn't know the height.)

The image is the logo of a university that logs into the system. So Its width and height are also different based on the university.

How can I place the logo at the center of the div as a watermark without having two divs? Is it possible?

Thanks
K

Comment: I apologize, I spaced the part of this being a background image. Are you ok with using background-size? It's not supported in IE8 and under. You'd need a javascript fall back.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
#test {
    background-image: url(path/to/image.jpg);
    background-size: 50% auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

This should put an image centered in it's parent element at a width that will be whatever percent you set. The image will be a background image. I believe IE8 and under will not display as you want. You will need to alter the image as I don't think you can adjust the opacity of a background image via CSS. So make the image semi-opaque.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MWvCA/

The other option is to add an absolute positioned img to the div, center it, and adjust the opacity via CSS, but if I were you I would just adjust the image.